# Google cloud Bigquery: Redshift Data transfer service permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to migrate redshift to BQ, and and few stating steps goes fine at the last step I am getting some permission denied error to table get.

```
Error code 7 : Access Denied: Table XXXXXXXXXX:MA_test.zip_code: The user redshift@bigquery-data-connectors.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table XXXXXXXXXX:MA_test.zip_code.
```

I also allowed the popup that popups when creating the  Redshift data transfer service.

[image]

Comment: Go to your projects IAM page. Locate the service account email `redshift@bigquery-data-connectors.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. Add `roles/
bigquery.dataViewer` to the service account. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Comment: Thanks, when I was previously trying to find this service account, It said that this account does not exists.

Comment: Did you find it now though?

Comment: yes, now it is sorted, was able to add the service account with required permission.